# Bash script to ssh to specific urls of a common format?

Tags: bash, ssh

All the vms at work I need to ssh into are of a common format (`stuff014.stuff.com`) with differing numbers. Is there a quick way to connect to them without making a big ssh config file and without using `alias`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Replace `<your_user_name>` with your user name.*)

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh <your_user_name>@stuff$1.stuff.com
```

The `$1` is the first parameter given, so if this was named `easyssh.sh` and you needed to get to `014` do

```
./easyssh.sh 014
```

To make this even better add it to a folder on your `PATH` (or add the directory to your path, whichever suits your needs).

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need a big config file. A minimal implementation only requires two lines.

```
host stuff*
    HostName %h.stuff.com
```

Any host you try to connect to is matched against the `host` patterns in your config file, stopping at the first one that matches. The `HostName` directive uses the matched host (`%h`) to construct the actual host name to connect to.

Then you can abbreviate the host name when running `ssh`:

```
$ ssh stuff014
# Connects to stuff014.stuff.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately the pattern is a lot longer and uglier than "stuff". :/ Is there a way to alias them in the config? Like `ssh a014` would be mapped to stuff014.stuff.com?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to process the value that `%h` expands to. The best I can think of is to use `ssh 014`, and `HostName stuff%h.stuff.com`. Also, it looks like `%h` might be a somewhat recent addition to what you can use with `HostName` (it's not mentioned in the man page for 5.3, but is for 6.2).